# removing zero entries from both arrays matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

how can we remove all the zero-pairs having 2 arrays in matlab?

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 0 5 0 7 0]
y = [0 2 0 1 1 2 5 2 7 0]
```

so that we obtain

```
x2 = [0 1 1 0 5 0 7]
y2 = [2 1 1 2 5 2 7]
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved quite easily using logical indexing:

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 0 5 0 7 0]
y = [0 2 0 1 1 2 5 2 7 0]

idx = ~(x==0 & y==0);

x2 = x(idx)
y2 = y(idx)
```

The array `idx` will have a `0` where `x` and `y` are both zero and a `1` otherwise. When you index using such an array, it will only return the values where the index is true (`1`).

**edit:** If you want to iterate it, just put a `for` loop around it. It is not hard, but with a vague description I can only give vague code (or very complicated code with cell arrays, which will be too complicated for what you actually need).

```
for i = ...
   x = % dependent on i
   y = % dependent on i

   idx = ~(x==0 & y==0);

   x2 = x(idx)
   y2 = y(idx)
end
```

Comment: and forgive me but I am not good in matalb yet, if i want to iterate this having i times x and i times y, how can i do it with for loop?

Answer (score 2):

You could write:

```
idx = any([x;y]);
```

or even better

```
idx = x|y;
```

then you apply logical indexing to select the elements:

```
x2 = x(idx)
y2 = y(idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

A compact alternative for positives using logical indexing, addition only and in-place modification:

```
idx = ~(x+y);
x(idx)=[];
y(idx)=[];
```

EDIT: For signed integers, where the corresponding elements in the two arrays might add up to zero, you can avoid the `==` or `~=` comparisons by

```
idx = ~(abs(x)+abs(y))
```

Comment: if they are positives (or same-sign for that matter), they cannot add-up to zero. true, though, that for a generic solution, and to avoid the `~=` or `==` comparisons, you can do `idx=~(abs(x)+abs(y))`